# Replacing multiple parts of a string value from a cell in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm importing the content of a CSV in a Google Spreadsheet. 
The problem I'm having is that the values come with some special characters, that I would like to remove.

I've tried to read up on the REGEXREPLACE function, but I can't figure out how I should use the regular expressions in my sheet.

For example I have the following cell with the following value:
A1 = Title:["*Title*"]

I would like to have a function that removes the **Title:["** from the beginning of the value, as well as the **"]** from the end.

Any ideas on how I could achieve that via a script?

Regards,
Thurstan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include links to similar questions and what you tried. See [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace() function for example:

```js
var SHEET_ID = '......';
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';

function myFunction() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
   var valueA1 = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
   valueA1 = valueA1.toString().replace('Title:["', '');
   valueA1 = valueA1.toString().replace('"]', '');
   sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(valueA1);
}
```